# L2 regularization increase the loss rate of the deep learning model

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

When I add L2 regularization to my deep learning model the training and validation loss rate is  increased.

Why ????

Answer (score 8):

Suppose a neural network with a regular loss function.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N L \left( y_i, \; \hat y_i \right)
$$

Here, $y_i$ is label for the $i$-th example, while $\hat y_i$ is the model's prediction for the same. The loss function $L$ is a function that compares the actual and the predicted output and outputs a value indicating how *close* the prediction was to the actual output.

[L2-regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)#Tikhonov_regularization) adds a **norm penalty** this loss function and as a result to each weight update.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N L\left( y_i, \; \hat y_i \right) + λ \cdot \|W\|_2^2 
$$

This penalty **counters** the actual update, meaning that it makes the weight updates harder. This has the effect of actually **increasing** the output your loss function.

What you should be looking for, by adding regularization to a model, isn't a reduction in training loss but a **reduction in the validation loss**. This would indicate that the regularization is successful in **reducing your model's overfitting**, which was its goal.

Comment: L2 increse the loss rate of both training and validation data.

Comment: Then maybe you are either regularizing too harshly or you didn't suffer from overfitting in the first place. Try reducing the regularization parameter ($λ$).

Comment: Better $\LaTeX$ code for norms is `\|` rather than `||`.